# Button takes up full screen no matter what

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I am making a tkinter program but have run into this issue.
I am trying to use the grid method to center a load of buttons in the middle of the screen(The amount of buttons will vary dynamically) However I cant keep the buttons to a reasonable size I have followed the advice of someone who had a similar problem however I cant figure out what I am doing differently as it hasn't solved my issue.
Here is my code (it uses a directory pathway so it won't work for the reader but maybe you can spot what I am doing wrong)

```
ef open_win3():
    global third_window
    third_window = Toplevel()
    third_window.config(height = 1800,width = 1800, bg = "chocolate1")
    create_thirdwindow_button()


def create_thirdwindow_button():
    bf = Frame(third_window,bg = "blue")
    bf.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky="NESW")
    bf.rowconfigure(0,weight = 1)
    bf.columnconfigure(0,weight =1)
    third_window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    third_window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    count = 0
    x = 1
    y = 0
    mypath = "C:\\Users\\link\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\python stuff\\screenshot example\\Snapshots by catagory"
    for g in listdir(mypath):
        count += 1

    for I in listdir(mypath):
        btp = mypath +"\\"+str(I)
        print(btp)
        screenshot_snap = Button(bf,text = str(I),width = 1,height = 1, bg =  "chocolate3",activebackground = "white",padx= 10,pady =10)
        screenshot_snap.grid(sticky = "NESW")
        screenshot_snap.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        screenshot_snap.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        x += 10
        if y < count:
            y += 1
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: ```screenshot_snap.grid(sticky = "NESW")```. I think you have set sticky as ```NESW``` which forces the widget to expand.

Comment: @Sujay ah I see I just thought it meant to center it. Because it would be the middle of North east ......    But I see why it could mean expand now